# Load xml file into multidimensional array

Tags: c#, xml, multidimensional-array, linq-to-xml

I am pulling my hair out trying to read an XML file into a two dimensional array.  I really do not know why the error is appearing. As a matter of fact I have not even done the array part yet.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<TERMINAL_MESSAGE_FILE>
    -<MESSAGE>
        <LABEL>LABEL1</LABEL>
        <MSG>MESSAGE1</MSG>
    </MESSAGE>
    -<MESSAGE>
       <LABEL>LABEL2</LABEL>
       <MSG>MESSAGE2</MSG>
    </MESSAGE>
</TERMINAL_MESSAGE_FILE>
```

All of the element values come from an array, messageArray[2].  It is possible that I am not creating this right as I am quite new to XML.

Now I am getting the file name from a file dialog control.  Here is the code I am using:

```
    class message
     {
       public string _label{ get; set; }
       public string _message{ get; set; }
     }

public partial class messageForm : Form
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private loadBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = openMsgFD.ShowDialog();

    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(openMsgFD.FileName);

        var settingsList = (from element in doc.Root.Elements("MESSAGE")
                           select new message
                           {
                                _label = element.Attribute("LABEL").Value,
                                _message= element.Attribute("MESSAGE").Value

                            }).ToList();

    // will need to deal with putting this into the array but I haven't got that far yet.
    }
}
```

So the error I get is "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
Thing is I copied this code from numerous examples that I have seen and some slightly different, but I always get this error. I tried using streamReader and streamWriter but there are carriage returns in the MESSGAE.VALUE so I cannot get that to work.
Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks, Tom

Comment: LABEL and MSG are child *Elements*, not *Attributes* of the MESSAGE element.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why a multidimensional array?  Why not a collection (`List<T>`) of the objects from the LINQ?  If label is unique, you could use a dictionary with label as key and message as value.

Answer (score 1):

As I hinted in the comment, LABEL and MSG are elements, not attributes.

First up, I would re-define message as below - in idiomatic C#, classes and properties are PascalCased:

```
public class Message
{
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public string Msg { get; set; }
}
```

Then this XLinq should work:

```
var settingsList = (from element in doc.Root.Elements("MESSAGE")
                    select new Message
                    {
                        Label = (string)element.Element("LABEL"),
                        Msg = (string)element.Element("MSG")

                    }).ToList();
```